# add view state from other table to select result

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables `reports` & `viewedids`
the first one stores data and the second one stores user IDs that viewed data:

viewedids:

```
+-------+------+
|  uid  | rid  |
+-------+------+
|   2   |   5  |
+-------+------+
```

each (`uid`,`rid`) means the `uid` has viewd `rid`

I want to select `*` from `reports` table and add view state (`0` or `1`) for current user to it. (A JOIN statement)
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT reports.*, viewedids.uid IS NOT NULL as view_state
FROM
  reports LEFT JOIN viewedids
  ON reports.id = viewedids.rid
     AND viewedids.uid = @current_user
```

This will return all reports, and will try to join reports table with viewedids ON `reports.id = viewedids.rid AND viewedids.uid = @current_user`. If the join succedes, viewedids.uid will be not null, and `viewedids.uid IS NOT NULL` will be evaluated to 1. It will be evaluated 0 otherwise.

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf5d59/1).